# Pushed before pulling - Lost changes

Tags: git, github, git-bash

So, I'm fairly new to using Git and while trying to push some changes, I forgot to pull first. I had added a README file in Github and forgotten to pull it locally. So when I tried to push my changes, it said that there are some files that I don't have locally and I need to pull them first. So I did and the README file in now in my local directory. But then when I retried to commit the changes it said: "On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean" and also the changes now aren't marked in Visual Studio. The changes do not appear on the repo either. I haven't lost any files or changes to existing ones locally but I can't push the changes now. Is there a way to get the changes back so I can push them (sort of a rescan)?

Comment: Have you tried `git push`?  (You don't *need* to redo `commit` because the changes were already committed.  The changes aren't marked in VS because they're already committed.)

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger This worked but shouldn't this be seen when I git status?

Comment: No.  (Or, more precisely, not the way you expected to see them.)  `git status` compares your worktree and index to the latest commit, and again your changes were already committed.  The only thing it tells you about what's in the remote is how far "ahead" or "behind" the branch is from the remote tracking ref.    So `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.` is how this is reflected by `git status`

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger OK Then is there a way to know if I've commited something without pushing it?

Comment: See the edit to my comment, as I filled in more detail about that.

Comment: And for more detail about what changes aren't pushed, you could `git diff master origin/master`

Comment: To check the local commits that are not pushed, you can check the log, `git log --oneline`